# Dataframe question: Enter new columns into df and create equations to get percentages

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Whats being asked is to essentially create new columns called "volume % change" and "close % change" which have the formula (current day close - previous day close)/(previous day close) and the same for volume. I cant seem to figure out how to get to desrired result where the output is the the new columns and their percentage values.

Current Code:

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import datetime 
import pandas as pd

print("\n---------------------------------------------------\n")
print("Stock Report Menu Options")
print("\n---------------------------------------------------\n")

print("1. Report changes for a stock ")
print("2. Quit")
  
answer = int(input())
while True:
    if answer == 1:
        print("\nPlease enter the stock symbol:")          
        stockPick = str(input())
        
        if True:
            print("\nPlease enter the number of days for the analysis:")
            requestedDays = int(input())
            
            def getStock(stk):
                
                print("\n******************************************************")
                
                dt = datetime.date.today() 

                dtPast = dt + datetime.timedelta(days= -requestedDays ) 
            
                print("\nDaily Percent Changes - " + str(dtPast) + " to " 
                      + str(dt) + " " + "* " + str(stockPick.upper()) + " *")
                
                print("\n******************************************************")
                
                df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stk, 

                     start= datetime.datetime(dtPast.year, dtPast.month, dtPast.day), 

                     end  = datetime.datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day)) 

                dfStock = getStock(stockPick.upper())          
                

                df['Volume % Change'] = (dfStock.iloc[numRows-1]['Volume'] 
                                        - dfStock.iloc[numRows-2])/(dfStock.iloc[numRows-2])
                df['Close % Change'] = (dfStock.iloc[numRows-1]['Close'] 
                                        - dfStock.iloc[numRows-2])/(dfStock.iloc[numRows-2])
                
                
                newColumnList = ['Date','Close','Close % Change']
                df = df[newColumnList]
                
                return 
            
            dfStock = getStock(stockPick.upper())
            print(dfStock)
           
                            
        else:
            print("Requested days must be an integer")              
                                        
    else:
        break
```

Whats being asked is to essentially create new columns called "volume % change" and "close % change" which have the formula (current day close - previous day close)/(previous day close) and the same for volume. I cant seem to figure out how to get to desrired result where the output is the code. This is my current attempt (which is code from inside the function):

```
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stk, 

                     start= datetime.datetime(dtPast.year, dtPast.month, dtPast.day), 

                     end  = datetime.datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day)) 
                               
                
                # df['Volume % Change'] = 
                df['Close % Change'] = (dfStock.iloc[numRows-1]['Close'] 
                                        - dfStock.iloc[numRows-2])/(dfStock.iloc[numRows-2])
                
                
                newColumnList = ['Date','Close','Close % Change']
                df = df[newColumnList]
                
                return 
            
            dfStock = getStock(stockPick.upper())
            print(dfStock)
```

Desired Output:
[image]

Any help or push in the right direction would be awesome!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given the dataframe df as shown below:

```
              Close      Volume
Date        
2021-01-15  212.649994  31691500
2021-01-19  216.440002  30480900
2021-01-20  224.339996  37770260
2021-01-21  214.544998  32086200
2021-01-24  220.389999  34125580  

deltac = df['Close'].pct_change()*100
deltav = df['Volume'].pct_change()*100   
for i in df.index:
    df.at[i, "Close % Change"] = deltac.loc[i]
for i in df.index:
    df.at[i, 'Vol % Change'] = deltav.loc[i]
```

Produces:

```
              Close      Volume   Close % Change    Vol % Change
Date                
2021-01-15  212.649994  31691500    NaN            NaN
2021-01-19  216.440002  30480900    1.782275    -3.819952
2021-01-20  224.339996  37770260    3.649969    23.914517
2021-01-21  214.544998  32086200    -4.366140   -15.049036
2021-01-24  220.389999  34125580    2.724371    6.355941
​
```